# Pseudo Inverse of Jacobian Matrix

Tags: inverse, jacobian, kinematics, robotics

I have a script written by someone else that outputs end-effector velocities. I need to transform
these end-effector velocities to joint velocities. This requires the pseudo-inverse of the Jacobian matrix $J(q)^{\dagger}$. The equation is shown below.

$\dot{q}=J(q)^{\dagger}\dot{x}$

The problem I am now facing is how to determine this pseudo inverse.

I know that for a very basic 2 DOF, $x, y$ manipulator we have the standard forward velocity kinematics:

$\dot{x}=J(q)\dot{q}$ in which:

$\begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{x} \\
    \dot{y} \\
 \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\partial x}{\partial q_1} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial q_2} \\
    \frac{\partial y}{\partial q_1} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial q_2} \\\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{q_1} \\
    \dot{q_2} \\\end{bmatrix}$

We can rewrite this expression to obtain the joint velocities:

$\dot{q}=J(q)^{\dagger}\dot{x}$ in which:

$\begin{bmatrix}
 \dot{q_1} \\
    \dot{q_2} \\\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 ?\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \dot{x} \\
    \dot{y} \\\end{bmatrix}$

I am wondering what should be put in the place of the question mark?

Comment: Are you sure $J(q)$ is singular? If it's *nonsingular*, $J(q)^\dagger = J(q)^{-1}$. Otherwise, since $J(q)$ is a 2x2 matrix, you can work through a standard construction of the pseudoinverse (e.g., [by SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Singular_value_decomposition_(SVD))) to come up with an expression. It may not necessarily be pretty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a powerpoint solving my question. Instead of re-entering all the matrices here, I simply paste images of the powerpoint slides. I hope this helps someone in the future:

[image]

[image]

[image]